# How to port Python program from gtk2 to gtk3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, gtk, pygtk, pyobject

We are trying to port [this program](https://github.com/Jooyeshgar/amir) from gtk2 to gtk3. When I try `pygi-convert.sh` I got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scripts/amir", line 53, in <module>
    from gi.repository import GObject
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/__init__.py", line 39, in <module>
    raise ImportError(_static_binding_error)
ImportError: When using gi.repository you must not import static modules like "gobject". Please change all occurrences of "import gobject" to "from gi.repository import GObject". See: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=709183
```

Any suggestion or other way to do this port?

Comment: Well, why not manually change that `import gobject` to `from gi.repository import GObject`?

Comment: @Aran-Fey Because when I did that, lots of errors occurred, do you have any other idea?

Comment: GTK4 is in the works, are you sure you want to do port it now?

Comment: @Aran-Fey I add a new branch https://github.com/Jooyeshgar/amir/tree/gtk3 and run the pygi-convert.sh and do some fixes but many features not working for now! any idea?

Comment: @gianmt: It'll be out in 2019 at best, and GTK+ 4 will still use gobject-instrospection, so porting to GTK+ 3 is not useless.

Answer (score 5):

First, try to understand what you're doing. Read the basics of [official Python for GTK+ 3 tutorial](https://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html). You'll see that the correct order to do imports is:

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk
```

The `pygi-convert.sh` is no silver bullet, you have to understand the changes and review them. For example the imports in [this section](https://github.com/Jooyeshgar/amir/commit/91d25e3d000d747c4f85102cc5db093883bea24a#diff-4bdddd3622fbde80c991375af07f4aa5L48) are most certainly wrong. The order is not correct, and you still have an `import gtk` left on the `import gtk,Gtk.glade` line. A `git grep -w gtk` should help you find all the lowercase `gtk` occurences in your code, which should be removed or replaced.

I also see you have in that same file some code to change the window theme. Theming changed completely between GTK+ 2 and GTK+ 3. GTK+ 3 uses a CSS engine.

Check out the [Python GTK+ 3 API](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Gtk-3.0) to know what's available, and check in the C migration guide (not aware of a python resource for that, sorry) [what has changed between GTK+ 2 and GTK+ 3](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk-migrating-2-to-3.html). Most things won't apply to python, but some will. For example migrating from the old `expose-event` to the `draw` signal when doing custom drawing, or checking which widgets have been killed and replaced.

Then try to run, fix errors, rinse, repeat.